# Segmentation Fault when copying content from argv[] to a char*

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, segmentation-fault, argv

I have seen some questions about this kinds of issues but none of them helped so far.

The code works fine on the console but the debugger tells that there happens a segmentation fault when I allocate memory for the pointer `*word`, on `main`, right after the `while` that contains a `switch` statement. It says that `argv[optind]` points to `NULL`, I assume its because during debug it has no values attributed to it.

So, if I feel like I know what happens, why am I asking this question, you may ask. Its because one of my classes uses an online code tester and my code is segfaulting there, so, I, not being very well versed in this, am not sure if its my fault.

The code runs as I posted it, you can compile and run, it searches for a word in a file of text; Example: `./my_grep "word" "file"`

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LINE 1000

static char* word=NULL;
int hasMultiWords=0, iflag=0, vflag=0, lflag=0, cflag=0;

void lowCase(char* s){
    //Nesta funcao recebe um apontador para o inicio de uma string, assim funciona com arrays in *char;
    for(int j=0; j<strlen(s); j++){
        *(s+j) = tolower(*(s+j));
    }

}

void readFile(FILE* in, FILE* out, int argc, char *file_name){

    char line[LINE];
    memset(line, 0, sizeof(char)*1000);
    int n_linhas=0;

    while( fgets(line, LINE, in) ){
        n_linhas++;
        if( cflag==1 && strstr(line, word) !=NULL ){
            printf("%d\n", n_linhas);
            continue;
        }
        if(iflag == 1){
            lowCase(word);
            char *ptr;
            ptr = &line[0];
            lowCase(ptr);
        }
        if( strstr(line, word) != NULL && vflag == 0){
            if(lflag == 1){
                fprintf(stdout, "%s", file_name); 
                break;
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        }
        if( strstr(line, word) != NULL && vflag == 1 ){
            if(lflag == 1){
                fprintf(stdout, "%s", file_name); 
                break;
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        }
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    FILE* read;
    char* file_name;
    int opt, weirdArgs=0;


    while( (opt=getopt(argc, argv, "ivlc")) != -1){
        switch(opt){
            case 'i':
                iflag=1;
                break;
            case'v':
                vflag=1;
                break;
            case 'l':
                lflag=1;
                break;
            case 'c':
                cflag=1;
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }
    }

    if(optind > 0){
        word = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[optind]));
        word = argv[optind];
    }

    optind++;

    for(; optind<argc; optind++){
        
        weirdArgs++;
        
        file_name = realloc(file_name, sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[optind]));
        file_name = argv[optind];

        if( strcmp(file_name, "-") == 0){
            readFile(stdin, stdout, argc, "stdin");
        }else{
            if( access(file_name, F_OK) != 0 ){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s : No such file.\n", file_name);
                continue;
            }   
            read = fopen(file_name, "r");
            readFile(read, stdout, argc, file_name);
            fclose(read);
        }
        free(file_name);
    }

    if(weirdArgs == 0) readFile(stdin, stdout, argc, "stdin");

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: So, its fixed, I added a if statement that checks if there are arguments and make the program print in `stderr` if there is not, thus it won't find out about the not assigned `optind`. Thank you!

```
if(argc == 1){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "No arguments found.\n"); 
        exit(2);
    }
```

Comment: `word = argv[optind];` overwrites word and loses the memory that you just got from malloc.

Comment: I got stuck before that.  My reading of the docs is that getopt() returns a tuple . . . not an integer.  So near as I can tell this shouldn't work at the console either.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you do not pass any arguments, or if you only pass argument switches, your program will have undefined behavior because the line `if (optind > 0)` does _not_ consider that `optind` may also be equal to or greater than `argc`.  And so `argv[optind]` is undefined.  As already mentioned, the `malloc`/`realloc` calls are only leaking memory.  Even if you were to use `strcpy` (as you should), you are not allocating enough bytes to include the string terminator, so again you'll have a problem.

Comment: @FrankMerrow: getopt returns a single character, which in C is an int. The return value is either the single-character option which was recognized or some special character indicating an error, or -1 indicating that the end of the argument list was reached. C doesn't have tuples.

Comment: Also, `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[optind]));` doesn't allocate space for the terminating null byte.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with what I said on that last EDIT:.
Since I don't even want the program to run if there are no arguments, I stop it before it reaches a point where errors can occur. So, if `argc` is equal to '1', meaning the only argument is the program path itself, it will `exit()` it, thus preventing the segmentation fault.

I should've think about this before posting, thank you for the feedback, I did use it to make it cleaner at least.